# Can't call method "getChildrenByTagNameNS" on unblessed reference?

Tags: multithreading, perl

i am new in threads and this is what i do :

```
my $thread_fifo = threads->create(sub {Plugins::Fifo->run($conf, $products, $workfifo)});
my $thread_liberty = threads->create(sub {Plugins::Fifo->run($conf, $products, $workliberty)});
```

and then : `$thread_fifo->join(); $thread_liberty->join();`

here is the Error message :

```
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Can't call method "getChildrenByTagNameNS" on unblessed reference at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/XML/Atom/Util.pm line 61.
```

To see what is `$thread_fifo` I use ref and Dumper :

`print ref($thread_fifo); # output : threads`

`print Dumper($thread_fifo); #output : $VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = '78589096')}, 'threads' );`

I know an unblessed reference error is where one variable is not a legal reference to an object, but yet trying to call a function on it as if it was a legal object, however i don't see where is the problem here, all i am trying to do is call two functions simultaneously.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't even show the code calling `getChildrenByTagNameNS`?!

Comment: There is no `getChildrenByTagNameNS` in my code, in the Error message you can see that is in `C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/XML/Atom/Util.pm`

Answer (score 2):

Not a full solution, but should be enough to see whats going on

```
threads->create(\&foobar,$products,$workfifo,'info');
threads->create(\&foobar,$products,$workliberty,'liberty');

# Master Thread
my @threads = threads->list();
for(my $i=0; $i<scalar(@threads); ++$i) {
  print STDERR "MASTER: about to join thread $i\n";
  my $thread = $threads[$i];
  eval {
    $thread->join();
  };
  if($@) {
    print STDERR "Caught error while joining thread $i ($@)\n";
  }
  else {
    print STDERR "MASTER: finished joining thread $i\n";
  }
}
@threads = threads->list();
print STDERR "I GOT " . scalar(@threads) . ", NOW EXITING\n";
exit;

# Child threads
sub foobar {
  my ($products,$work,$str) = @_;
  print STDERR "CHILD $str: STARTING\n";
  Plugins::Fifo->run($conf, $products, $work);
  print STDERR "CHILD $str: ENDING\n";
}
```

Comment: I get `Can't call method "join" on an undefined value at ...`

Comment: I added a little more debugging, can you tell me your (1) use statements atop your file (2) output from running this & (3) which of your 2 join statements is causing error? Thanks.